# Solidity, Can Attacker bypass a internal functions?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

I'm thinking about my smart contract and want to have a secure contract. But I really don't know that internal functions are safe or not.
This is a very BASIC contract that uses `OpenZeppelin` contracts:

```
contract MyContract is ERC20 {
    constructor () ERC20("test", "test") {    
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }
}
```

_mint is an internal function from Openzeppelin ERC20 contract.
Can someone deploy another contract and call the MyContract _mint() function?
If yes, How can we secure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`_mint()` from ERC20 is **internal**](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/ac30219a6a0eb9f98798da39ddef7fe554e43616/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L251).

Internal functions can only be called **within the contract** or by the **contracts inherited from the current one**.

That means that no other contract can call `MyContract._mint()`, you can only call `_mint()` from inside `MyContract`.